# Open Application from URL with http

Tags: ios, swift

How to Open URL directly from URL ?
Like in notes if we have URL www.facebook.com then it directly opens Facebook App even if we have internet connection off.

I tried the method where we add URL in Info.plist but in that it detects like this `abc://*` not for abc.com

Comment: Where do you want to apply this feature? do you mean in UITextView? have you tried to implement it? if yes, please add it as a code snippet.

Comment: @AhmadF No. I want to open my Application when user taps on the url from any other app or email/message.

Comment: You need to  use Url Schema for that

Comment: @ivarun I tried URL Schema but it works for url like this only `abc://` not on `abc.com`

Comment: Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZADKJwsllqg, it is called deep linking in iOS.

Comment: @AnuraagDJain  but it cannot support URL with http

Comment: Try typing Facebook.com in Notes and click on it. I want to have behaviour like that.

Comment: What you mean is http://myapp.com/xyz should open your app?

Comment: Yes. It should directly open the app if clicked on that URL

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is ***Universal Links***:

> When you support universal links, iOS users **can tap a link to your**
>   **website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without**
>   **going through Safari**. If your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to
>   your website opens your website in Safari.

The **output** after supporting Universal Links:

[image]

---

For supporting Universal Links, I would recommend to check:

- [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) Apple Documentation.
- [iOS Universal Links](https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/iOS-Universal-Links) GitHub Repo.

Comment: No this one is different. See, try adding Facebook.com in Notes and tap on that. It will directly open Facebook even if we are not connected to internet